# How to replace the lower case letters to upper case letter 'C' using awk?

Tags: awk

I have a text file with protein sequences. I would like to replace all the lowercase letters to upper case letter 'C'. How can I do this with awk?

```
>1CHE
aHKLbMaHc
>2HV3
PNMRrYnf
>5GH3
LKDeVmqQ

desired output

>1CHE
CHKLCMCHC
>2HV3
PNMRCYCC
>5GH3
LKDCVCCQ
```

Comment: @SaddamAbuGhaida: I think the OP is just looking to change the protein sequence, not the name of the sequences. `tr` is probably not appropriate. Although the question is not that well defined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `sed` for this:

```
sed '/^>/!s/[a-z]/C/g' file.txt
```

If you'd like the `awk`, here it is:

```
awk '!/^>/ { gsub(/[a-z]/, "C") }1' file.txt
```

Results:

```
>1CHE
CHKLCMCHC
>2HV3
PNMRCYCC
>5GH3
LKDCVCCQ
```

Answer (score 6):

```
echo 'changecase' | tr [:lower:] C
```

Comment: In ZSH, the `[:lower:]` needs to be quoted.